# Element overlapping navigation menu when scrolling

Tags: html, css, navbar

When I scroll down on my page the orange text at the top of my page overlaps the navigation menu. I do not know why this is happening and I've tried for example to remove the `float: left;` code and the `position: relative;` code as I thought they might be the problem, but no. I would like to have the orange text under the navbar when you scroll. Any help is appreciated.

```js
function toggleMobileMenu(menu) {
    menu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200vh;
}
header {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: rgba(120, 126, 133, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(120, 126, 133, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
}
header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
header ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
header ul a {
    color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
}
nav {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-bottom: 0.6em;
    padding-top: 0.6em;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(120, 126, 133, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a, nav ul li a:after, nav ul li a:before {
    transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #555;
}
nav.stroke ul li a, nav.fill ul li a {
    position: relative;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:after, nav.fill ul li a:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 0%;
    content: '.';
    color: transparent;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 1px;
}
nav.fill ul li a {
    transition: all 2s;
}
nav.fill ul li a:after {
    text-align: left;
    content: '.';
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    z-index: 1;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover:after {
    z-index: -10;
    animation: fill 0.6s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: fill 0.6s forwards;
    -moz-animation: fill 0.6s forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}
.header-img {
    display: none;
}
nav img {
    width: 80px;
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
    image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
#hamburger-icon {
  margin: auto 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 21.845px;
  padding-bottom: 21.845px;
}
#hamburger-icon div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 8px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.open .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
}
.open .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.open .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}
.open .mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgba(120, 126, 133, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 84.69px;
}
.mobile-menu li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
@keyframes fill {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
        height: 2px;
    }
    50% {
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgb(199, 199, 199);
    }
}
.fake {
    display: none;
}
.Iam {
    padding: 2em;
    font: normal 40px/50px Montserrat, sans-serif;
    color: #999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
}
.Iam p {
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.Iam b {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    top: 40px;
}
.Iam .innerIam {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e74c3c;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
   /*animation*/
    -webkit-animation:move 5s;
    -moz-animation:move 5s;
    -ms-animation:move 5s;
    -o-animation:move 5s;
    animation:move 5s;
   /*animation-iteration-count*/
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   /*animation-delay*/
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1s;
    -o-animation-delay:1s;
    animation-delay:1s;
}
@keyframes move{
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@keyframes move {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 920px) {
    nav ul li a {
        padding: 0px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    header nav {
      display: none;
    }
    #hamburger-icon {
      display: block;
    }
    .header-img {
        display: block;
    }
    .header-img img{
        width: 80px;
        height: 61px;
        image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
        image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
        image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
        image-rendering: crisp-edges;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    header {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .fake {
        display: block;
        width: 80px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-top: 4em;
    }
    .Iam b {
        top: 30px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 592px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .Iam b {
        top: 25px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 494px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 5em;
    }
    .Iam b {
        top: 20px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 395px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 356px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-top: 6em;
    }
    .Iam b {
        top: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
        <div class="header-img"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bblqj5b.png" alt="SCP"></div>
        <nav class="fill">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bblqj5b.png" alt="SCP"></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="wwd.html">What we do</a></li>
            <li><a href="effects.html">Effects</a></li>
            <li><a href="wycd.html">What you can do</a></li>
            <li><a href="lildicky.html">Earth by Lil Dicky</a></li>
            <li><a href="formular.html">Form</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="hamburger-icon" onclick="toggleMobileMenu(this)">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
          <ul class="mobile-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="wwd.html">What we do</a></li>
              <li><a href="effects.html">Effects</a></li>
              <li><a href="wycd.html">What you can do</a></li>
              <li><a href="lildicky.html">Earth by Lil Dicky</a></li>
              <li><a href="formular.html">Form</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="fake"></div>
      </header>
      <div class="Iam">
        <p>We need to</p>
        <b>
          <div class="innerIam">
            stop climate pollution<br> 
            help the world<br>
            work together<br>
            don't mess up<br>
            and fix the climate<br>
          </div>
        </b>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the z-index of the header higher than the other parts ;)

```js
function toggleMobileMenu(menu) {
    menu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200vh;
}
header {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: rgba(120, 126, 133, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(120, 126, 133, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
    z-index: 199;
}
header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
header ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
header ul a {
    color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
}
nav {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-bottom: 0.6em;
    padding-top: 0.6em;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(120, 126, 133, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
    z-index: 100;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a, nav ul li a:after, nav ul li a:before {
    transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #555;
}
nav.stroke ul li a, nav.fill ul li a {
    position: relative;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:after, nav.fill ul li a:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 0%;
    content: '.';
    color: transparent;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 1px;
}
nav.fill ul li a {
    transition: all 2s;
}
nav.fill ul li a:after {
    text-align: left;
    content: '.';
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    z-index: 1;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover:after {
    z-index: -10;
    animation: fill 0.6s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: fill 0.6s forwards;
    -moz-animation: fill 0.6s forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}
.header-img {
    display: none;
}
nav img {
    width: 80px;
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
    image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
#hamburger-icon {
  margin: auto 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 21.845px;
  padding-bottom: 21.845px;
}
#hamburger-icon div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 8px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.open .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
}
.open .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.open .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}
.open .mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgba(120, 126, 133, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 84.69px;
}
.mobile-menu li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
@keyframes fill {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
        height: 2px;
    }
    50% {
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgb(199, 199, 199);
    }
}
.fake {
    display: none;
}
.Iam {
    padding: 2em;
    font: normal 40px/50px Montserrat, sans-serif;
    color: #999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
}
.Iam p {
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.Iam b {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    top: 40px;
}
.Iam .innerIam {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e74c3c;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
   /*animation*/
    -webkit-animation:move 5s;
    -moz-animation:move 5s;
    -ms-animation:move 5s;
    -o-animation:move 5s;
    animation:move 5s;
   /*animation-iteration-count*/
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   /*animation-delay*/
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1s;
    -o-animation-delay:1s;
    animation-delay:1s;
}
@keyframes move{
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@keyframes move {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
   }
    20% {
        top: -50px;
   }
    40% {
        top: -100px;
   }
    60% {
        top: -150px;
   }
    80% {
        top: -200px;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 920px) {
    nav ul li a {
        padding: 0px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    header nav {
      display: none;
    }
    #hamburger-icon {
      display: block;
    }
    .header-img {
        display: block;
    }
    .header-img img{
        width: 80px;
        height: 61px;
        image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
        image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
        image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
        image-rendering: crisp-edges;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    header {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .fake {
        display: block;
        width: 80px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-top: 4em;
    }
    .Iam b {
        top: 30px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 592px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .Iam b {
        top: 25px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 494px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 5em;
    }
    .Iam b {
        top: 20px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 395px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 356px) {
    .Iam {
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-top: 6em;
    }
    .Iam b {
        top: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
        <div class="header-img"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bblqj5b.png" alt="SCP"></div>
        <nav class="fill">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bblqj5b.png" alt="SCP"></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="wwd.html">What we do</a></li>
            <li><a href="effects.html">Effects</a></li>
            <li><a href="wycd.html">What you can do</a></li>
            <li><a href="lildicky.html">Earth by Lil Dicky</a></li>
            <li><a href="formular.html">Form</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="hamburger-icon" onclick="toggleMobileMenu(this)">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
          <ul class="mobile-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="wwd.html">What we do</a></li>
              <li><a href="effects.html">Effects</a></li>
              <li><a href="wycd.html">What you can do</a></li>
              <li><a href="lildicky.html">Earth by Lil Dicky</a></li>
              <li><a href="formular.html">Form</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="fake"></div>
      </header>
      <div class="Iam">
        <p>We need to</p>
        <b>
          <div class="innerIam">
            stop climate pollution<br> 
            help the world<br>
            work together<br>
            don't mess up<br>
            and fix the climate<br>
          </div>
        </b>
      </div>
</body>
```